# QT launch member of class function in thread

Tags: c++, qt

Not so long ago, I started programming in C++. I have a `Joint_S1i` class and I need to run its void `Joint_S1i::runBufferController()` function in a separate thread. In the QT documentation for threads, the example creates a separate class that moves to a separate thread via `moveToThread`, but I want to just run the function of the already created class in the thread. What I tried:

### 1 moveToThread

```
m_thread = new QThread();
moveToThread(m_thread);
connect(m_thread, &QThread::started, this, &Joint_S1i::runBufferController);
m_thread->start();
```

### 2 QtConcurrent::run

```
QtConcurrent::run(this, static_cast<void(Joint_S1I::*)()>(&Joint_S1I::runBufferController));
```

When I run the program with both options, the application crashes. It crashes on the start of threads. In the debagger, I see these messages:

```
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QBufferPrivate'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
RTTI symbol not found for class 'QThreadPool'
```

Here is minimal reproduce example

### .pro

```
QT -= gui
QT += core network concurrent

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
    datatransmissionchannel.cpp \
    joint_s1i.cpp

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    datatransmissionchannel.h \
    joint_s1i.h
```

### datatransmissionchannel.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QThread>
#include <QBuffer>

class DataTransmissionChannel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DataTransmissionChannel(const quint16 &portIn,
                                     const quint16 &portOut,
                                     const QHostAddress &host = QHostAddress::LocalHost,
                                     QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void runBufferController();

protected:
    QTcpServer *m_tcpServerIn = nullptr;
    QTcpServer *m_tcpServerOut = nullptr;
    QTcpSocket *m_tcpClientIn = nullptr;
    QTcpSocket *m_tcpClientOut = nullptr;
    quint16 m_portIn;
    quint16 m_portOut;
    QHostAddress m_host;
    bool m_opened;
    QBuffer m_buffer;
    qint64 m_maxBufferSize = 10000000;
};
```

### datatransmissionchannel.cpp

```
#include "datatransmissionchannel.h"

DataTransmissionChannel::DataTransmissionChannel(
        const quint16 &portIn,
        const quint16 &portOut,
        const QHostAddress &host,
        QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_host = host;
    m_portIn = portIn;
    m_portOut = portOut;
    m_tcpServerIn = new QTcpServer(this);
    m_tcpServerOut = new QTcpServer(this);
    m_tcpServerIn->listen(m_host, m_portIn);
    m_tcpServerOut->listen(m_host, portOut);
}

void DataTransmissionChannel::runBufferController()
{
    while(m_opened) {
        bool emptyBuffer = false;
        if (m_buffer.size() < m_maxBufferSize * 0.2)
            emptyBuffer = true;
        if (m_buffer.size() > m_maxBufferSize * 0.8)
            emptyBuffer = false;
        if (emptyBuffer && m_tcpClientIn)
            m_tcpClientIn->write("Need data");
        if (m_buffer.size() == 0)
            this->thread()->sleep(1);
    }
}
```

### joint_s1i.h

```
#include "datatransmissionchannel.h"

class Joint_S1I : public DataTransmissionChannel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Joint_S1I(const quint16 &portIn = 42599,
                       const quint16 &portOut = 42600,
                       const QHostAddress &host = QHostAddress::LocalHost,
                       QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void run();
};
```

### joint_si1.cpp

```
#include "joint_s1i.h"
#include "QtConcurrent"


Joint_S1I::Joint_S1I(const quint16 &portIn,
                     const quint16 &portOut,
                     const QHostAddress &host,
                     QObject *parent) :
    DataTransmissionChannel(portIn, portOut, host, parent)
{
}

void Joint_S1I::run()
{
    m_opened = true;
    m_buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    QtConcurrent::run(this, static_cast<void(Joint_S1I::*)()>(&Joint_S1I::runBufferController));
    m_buffer.close();
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "joint_s1i.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Joint_S1I joint_S1I;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the problem here is not in running the function in a separate thread. The thread starts well. The problem is in my buffer. I use the `QBuffer` class, which is not thread-safe. First, I opened the buffer for read/write, and then I tried to start a thread that should have access to the same `QBuffer` object. That was the problem. I tried to start the stream without opening the buffer and everything worked. Here is a working version:

```
QtConcurrent::run(this, static_cast<void(Joint_S1i::*)()>(&Joint_S1i::runBufferController));
```